# run macro on Save of Another Workbook from XLSM file

Tags: excel, vba, save

Hi Guys i have a small issue that I need help with.

I got a xlsm file named **"vba.xlsm"** that I have set in a directory to be automatically open when any excel file is open. This using open At Startup Option of excel.

[image]

Now i need to run a a code on the xlsm file, when any file is saved.
The code is in the the xlsm file, lets , and need to be run when any excel file is opened and saved.

Any ideas on how i can achieve this?

Clarification :

I have a folder in my local drive "C:\xls" where i have a xlsm file "vba.xlsm".

This vba.xlsm is opened **every time** a excel workbook is open or created.

in this vba.xlsm there is a piece of code that i need to be executed **everytime** a workbook is saved.

Is there a way i can garantee my code in vba.xlsm is run when a workbook is saved?

I have tried the Workbook_BeforeSave and Workbook_AfterSave events, but these are only fired if the vba.xlsm is saved, not if other workbook is saved.

Any idea how i can detect the save event of another workbook from my vba.xlsm ?

@TimWilliams

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "saveEvent"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Public WithEvents appevent As Application
Attribute appevent.VB_VarHelpID = -1
    
Private Sub appevent_WorkbookAfterSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal Success As Boolean)
   MsgBox Wb.Name & "Saved"
End Sub

Private Sub appevent_WorkbookBeforeSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
   MsgBox Wb.Name & "Before Save"
End Sub
```

ThisWorkbook of vba.xlsm

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Dim objSaveEvent As New saveEvent
  Set objSaveEvent.appevent = Application
End Sub
```

Comment: I thought the personal.xlsm was always open and available - unless you closed it?

Comment: this another xlsm, that has a code that need to run on save of other workbooks

Comment: You can look into Application events

Comment: So? a macro in the Personal.xlsm is available to all workbooks.

Comment: yes the macro is in vba.xlsm that is configure to open when any workbook is open

Comment: your post is not clear, you can try Application.Run "'vba.xlsm'!moduleName.procedureName", arg1, arg2

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/create-application-level-event-handler

Comment: @MukibulHasan I clarify a bit more what i am triying to achieve,

Comment: @TimWilliams i tried but for some reason my events are not fired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture application events but you do this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Dim objSaveEvent As New saveEvent      '<< your app event-capturing class
  Set objSaveEvent.appevent = Application
End Sub
```

...then as soon as `Workbook_Open` is complete, your `objSaveEvent` object goes out of scope and disappears, so no events will get intercepted.

You need something like this...

In the `ThisWorkbook` module of your "vba.xlsm":

```
Dim objSaveEvent As saveEvent 'global, for persistence

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Set objSaveEvent = New saveEvent 'populate Global object
  Set objSaveEvent.appevent = Application
End Sub
```

Class module `saveEvent`:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents appevent As Application
  
Private Sub appevent_WorkbookAfterSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, _
                                       ByVal Success As Boolean)
   MsgBox Wb.Name & " Saved"
End Sub

Private Sub appevent_WorkbookBeforeSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, _
                                        ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
                                        Cancel As Boolean)
   MsgBox Wb.Name & " Before Save"
End Sub
```

Comment: you are correct that was a novice mistake let me test it,

Comment: Man i made a noob mistake and forgot the scope of the variable

Comment: Can you edit this answer and put the whole solution so if someone else needs it they can see it, you can copy the example code i put up